# Laravel : Removing Array item from Session

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I was trying to remove array item from Session. I have shown the array element following way:

```
<?php $i=1; ?>

@foreach(Session::get('product') as $row)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="{{asset('files/'.$row->thumbnil)}}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="" width="90px">
        </td>
        <td>{{$row->name}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{asset('deleteEnquote/'.$row->id)}}">  
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php $i++; ?>  
@endforeach
```

And this is how I was trying to remove the key element :

```
public function deleteEnquote($id)
{

    $remove = Product::where('id',$id)->first();

    if(Session::has('product')){
        foreach (Session::get('product') as $key => $value) {
            if($value === $remove){
                Session::pull('product.'.$key); // retrieving pen and removing
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return redirect('enquote');
}
```

But the problem is I couldn't delete the appropriate element from the Array.Means element not deleted.How do I delete the specific element from Session Array?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

1. Get the array.
2. Using `unset` function remove that key.
3. Set the updated array again to session with same key.

   ```
   $product = Session::get('product'); //step 1
   unset($product[$key]);              //step 2
   Session::put('product', $product);  //step 3
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If **product** is your session array then use following code:

```
if(Session::has('product')){
  foreach (Session::get('product') as $key => $value) {
    if($value === $remove){
      session()->forget('product.'.$key)
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. please update your answer to explain how it addresses the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)